# Mongo ODM near query does not populate distance property. It is null?

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine-mongodb

According to Mongo ODM one should be able to get distance after a near query:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/geospatial-queries.html#distance

When I use the near query as it shows in the documentation, I am able to get results however the distance never gets added.

Here is my query:

```
 $query = $dm->createQueryBuilder('SomeBundle:Blah')
        ->select('id', 'name', 'distance', 'propertyType', 'squareFootage')->field('coordinates')->near($latitude, $longitude);

$results = $query->getQuery()->execute();


foreach ($results as $city) {
    echo $city->name.': '.$city->distance."\n";
}
```

My distance property is set up as :

```
   /** @MongoDB\Distance */
    public $distance;
```

I get no results. Is there a bug with Mongo ODM?

Comment: try to extract the mongo query and try to query via console. (for debugging)

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using

```
$query->near($latitude, $longitude);
```

you need to use

```
$query->geoNear($latitude, $longitude)
```

if you want distance to be populated.

Comment: and it's $query->geoNear($longitude, $latitude); for correct distance value if index is spherical